# Why is my css transition property not happening gradually based on the transition duration

Tags: css, reactjs, css-transforms

So I have two boxes called left panel and right panel and an overlay with position:absolute on top of right panel. There is a sign up button on right panel and on click I am adding a noghost class (so that the overlay is visible then).

What I am intending is the when I click on the button on the right side panel the overlay should translateX to the left. What I notice is that it happens instantaneously whenever this class comes up.
What am I doing wrong

Html

```css
.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  background: yellow;
  top: 0%;
  opacity: 0.7;
  transition: all 1.8s linear;
  z-index: 10;
  }

.trigger.noghost .overlay{
  
  transform: translateX(-250px);
}
```

```html
<div
    className={`trigger ${
    activePanel === 'SignIn' ? 'noghost' : 'ghost'
    }` }    
    >
      <div className="overlay" />
</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 1):

The way I fix my issue was I did add a default position, like in your case:

```
transform: translateX(0);
```

This is also to help you understand what properties are changing in your element.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/397bges5/)

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-keller-mnu2k?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)